# Inline assembly in C code using TI code composer studio (for ARM)

Tags: assembly, arm, code-composer

Could somebody tell me please how can I execute inline assembly code in C code using TI code composer studio (for ARM)?

I searched and tried but nothing worked.

For example, when I try this very simple code:

```
asm("push r0\n");
```

or this

```
__asm("push r0\n");
```

I always get:

> [E0002] Illegal mnemonic specified    push r0
>
> 1 Assembly Error, No Assembly Warnings

I read something says that my previous code is GCC style,and TI compiler doesn't accept it!. Then how can I execute my own inline assembly codes?

Comment: inline assembly is very much compiler specific, so there is no expectation that inline assembly will port from one compiler version or brand to another.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I found the solution!!

the main problem will be solved by adding a space or tab before the assembly instruction like this:

```
asm(" MOVS R0, #5\n");
```

This won't work:

```
asm("MOVS R0, #5\n");
```

And in push we have to put the register in braces {R0}

```
asm(" PUSH {R0}\n");
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: That (the space) is strange, but ok, lessons learned. Thank you for telling us your solution. UV

Comment: The space is required so that the assembler doesn't interpret the instruction as a label.  Same as for normal assembly files.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know an ARM Code Composer Studio. But I knew a TI Code Composer Studio and if the is meant, I could give you some hints. Use `asm volatile ("...")` might help. But with that method you can not access to C variables for example. It's much better to use so called intrinsic functions/methods which are functions that link C to assembler. Here is a link to a TI document:  http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spru187o/spru187o.pdf section 7.5.4. Here is the link from which I got the idea: https://e2e.ti.com/support/development_tools/code_composer_studio/f/81/t/3660

Comment: I really meant TI ccs (I edited the name). unfortunately, volatile method didn't work, I still get the same error. I am gonna read what you sent to me and tell you what I get. thanks.

Comment: Perhaps it's as simple as write uppercase PUSH  and use {} for the register lists. But that's only a guess.  `asm ("PUSH {r0}\n")`

Comment: And I really should have read your last sentence. ;-) TI Compiler should know the ARM mneomonics but if not, then PUSH is an alias for `STMDB sp!, reglist` as you can read here  http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489e/Babefbce.html

Comment: ("PUSH {r0}\n") that didn't work :( . I am reading the links you sent to me (they are a little bit comlicated but I am trying).

Comment: linked document is to their DSP compiler not arm